# Can I use \copydoc with function or template parameters?

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameters, doxygen

In doxygen, there is the `\copydoc` (or `@copydoc`) command that allows to copy the documentation text of a link-object, which can point to a:

> member (of a class, file or group), a class, a namespace, a group, a page, or a file

That's a nice feature and it works well, but I would like to copy the documentation of a template parameter from another class, but those don't have fully qualified names.

Is there any way to make that possible?

Comment: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/8159